# Plotting a curve through a slope field in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph-visualization

I'm using the following Python code (taken from another SO post that I cannot recall) to graph the slope field of the differential equation dy/dx = 1/(x+y):

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

# Differential equation
# diff = y'= y/x (or say x+y)
def diff(x,y):
    if (x+y == 0):
        return 0
    else:
        return 1/(x+y) # try also x+y

x = np.linspace(-3,3,25)
y = np.linspace(-3,3,25)

# use x,y
for j in x:
    for k in y:
        slope = diff(j,k)
        domain = np.linspace(j-0.07,j+0.07,2)
        def fun(x1,y1):
            z = slope*(domain-x1)+y1
            return z
        plt.plot(domain,fun(j,k),solid_capstyle='projecting',solid_joinstyle='bevel')

plt.title("Slope field y'")
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
    
print("End of the program")
```

I now want to plot a curve (say, y = -x - 1) through this same slope field.

How could I go about this?

Comment: `plt.plot(x, -x-1)` before `plt.show()`

Comment: @gboffi got it! Thank you very much for the assistance.